# How to handle Empty Uri's for Path Binding to an Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

how can I initialize an Uri object in an empty state.

First thought would be to do something like this

```
//does not work
Uri myUri = Uri.Empty
```

This one does also not work

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(string.Empty)
```

The reason is I store my image path in the db and in case there is no image defined I have a blank database record.

I know that there are ways to handle this with a converter and return a default blank image Uri in case the image_path is empty...

How do I handle the binding to my ViewModel Uri Property best?

Is the converter the way to go and how do you handle it if you would have like many different default images which should be returned...

Answer (score 26):

Just set:

```
new Uri("about:blank");
```

Works for me.

Comment: Surprisingly, the result is really nice: [Linqpad Test](https://imgur.com/a/IqbcbE8)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
Uri uri = null;
bool someValue = Context.TryGetUri(entity, out uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to handle this is you can alter your data query for example if you are using from sql employees table then you could write as like below.

```
select Employeeid, FirstName, LastName, 
case when ImageUrl is null then 'http://www.codeodor.com/images/Empty_set.png' else ImageUrl end as ImageUrl from employees
```

this will handle the null and return an default url for the empty image;

hope it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and after thinking a while I believe there isn't a default constructor for `System.Uri` because it doesn't make sense.
Indeed, an `URI` identifies a resource, therefore if the resource doesn't exist or cannot be located, I think the best approach is to deal with a `null` reference instead of an empty `Uri`.

In your code, instead of having (pseudo-code):

```cs
if (myUri != Uri.Empty)
{
    // do something
}
```

you'll have:

```cs
if (myUri != null)
{
   // do something
}
```

In this case you can use also the [Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx), if it fits your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I use this my custome Uri class in all Project :

---

```
public class URI : Uri
{
    public static readonly Uri Empty = new URI("about:blank");
    public URI(string uriString) : base(uriString) 
    {
    }
    public URI(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri) : base(baseUri, relativeUri)
    {
    }
    public URI(string uriString, UriKind uriKind) : base(uriString, uriKind)
    {
    }
    public URI(Uri baseUri, string? relativeUri) : base(baseUri, relativeUri)
    { 
    }
    public URI(string uriString, in UriCreationOptions creationOptions) : base(uriString, creationOptions) 
    { 
    }
    protected URI(SerializationInfo serializationInfo, StreamingContext streamingContext) : base(serializationInfo, streamingContext) 
    {
    }
}
```

---

Example use URI class :

---

```
Uri uri = URI.Empty;
```

---